# Jquery function return order issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript, I am calling same function 3rd times but return order changes every time. You can see my code in the below. Sometimes page1.html is first loaded sometime page2.html

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        addHtml('page1');
        addHtml('page2');
        addHtml('page3');
    });
});

function addHtml(url) {
    if ($("#" + url).length == 0) {
        $.get(url+'.html', function (result) {
            $('.divtest').append(result);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: One important point to consider is what should happen if say `$("#page2").length` is not `0`. Should it halt or should it attempt `page3`? If it should continue, then it would still seem beneficial to make all requests at the same time so that the overall time it takes is simply that of the longest request instead of the sum of all requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        addHtml('page1', function(){
          // page 1 added
          addHtml('page2', function(){
            // page 2 added
            addHtml('page3', function(){
              // All HTML added
            });
          });
        });
    });
});

function addHtml(url, callback) {
    if ($("#" + url).length == 0) {
        $.get(url+'.html', function (result) {
            $('.divtest').append(result);
            callback();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you so much.

Comment: The only inconvenient is the nested callbacks. They're very ugly. As a simple solution is nice, but Promises come to us to pretiffy our code =)

Comment: Isn't it callback hell?? and there is no need to return `callback()`

Comment: Yes it's a hell once you know to work with promises. And yes there's no need to return callback() just call callback() and works!

Comment: Promises only exist because people don't think through how to cleanly structure their code to avoid the rightward drift. Given this simple case, both nested callbacks and promises are far more verbose than needed. https://jsfiddle.net/z0utxqse/

Comment: ...oops, I messed up the variable name in the demo above. https://jsfiddle.net/ntey03fs/

Comment: As nicest as simplest!

Answer (score 3):

It is because you using http call to get page html is asynchronous, means non-blocking. So, it depends on response time, which page will be added first.

You can return promise `return $.get(url+'.html')` and then chain them in order.

```
function addHtml(url) {
    return $.get(url+'.html');
};

$("#button").click(function () {
    addHtml('page1')
    .then(function(result){
        $('.divtest').append(result);
        return addHtml('page2');
     })
    .then(function(result){
        $('.divtest').append(result);
        return addHtml('page3');
     })
     .then(function(result){
        $('.divtest').append(result);
     })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. So how can I call the functions 2nd time after first response is completed. Is there any way?

Comment: Let me edit my answer, and add a better example

Comment: This is really good example. Thank you.

Comment: His original code has a `if ($("#" + url).length == 0) {` test that you've removed for some reason. What should be returned from `addHtml` if that condition fails?

Comment: we can check that condition before calling that function. A function should have a single responsibility

Comment: You mean put that condition around each `addHtml` call? That doesn't seem very DRY and would make the solution quite a bit more verbose, unless I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: yeah, you are right, that is bad.

Comment: I've never used Promises, but I would think there would be a way to return some sort of a no-op promise so that the chaining doesn't break. Question is if it should allow the next `.then()` to continue or not.

Comment: No, it will  fail, I have to add some code to  make it full proof.